# PHP MySQL Get Specific Value When Result Show

Tags: php, mysql

How to get specific value of query in MySQL.

My code :

```
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tb_post WHERE post LIKE '%#%'");
while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
{
     $post = $d['post'];
}
```

Example data result like this :

```
I'm groot #me
What are you doing #what
Sometimes I felt like superman #me
I don't know what to do #confuse
```

Now, my question is : is it possible to get just hashtag? Example : #me, #what, #confuse.
So I do not need another value.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$post = $d['post'];
$whatIWant = substr($post, strpos($post, "#") + 1);    
echo "#" . $whatIWant . "<br />";
```

Output:

```
#me
#what
#me
#confuse
```

Comment: 1 question, how can I get most hashtag and group it ?

Comment: @hiDayurie there are different solutions and change if the hastags are saved in a array or a string! But i would say that's another question ;D

Comment: Thanks btw. If you have time, please post it here :)